# How do you write a value returned by external javascript to a file using php?

Tags: php, javascript, file

I have a table with a button which onClick calls an external javascript file, which calculates some values and returns them to the table. I need to then write that value back to a file using PHP without leaving the current page. Is there any way to do this? I thought about trying onChange, but I wasn't sure how ot make that work with php since it's usually a javascript call.

Answer (score 0):

PHP is executed on your server
the javascript file, even if external, is run on the client machine.

You can't use PHP on the client machine! You must use javascript to call a php script, stored in your server, that do what you need to.

You're on the good track, you need to use AJAX calls in your javascript.

Answer (score 0):

1. don't use `onclick`, search for unobtrusive javascript;
2. you'd be using jQuery, so you can use its [`ajax` handler](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/);
3. find out a good reading about the whole topic, before going heads down on writing code.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like something you could solve by using [AJAX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29). Basically you would communicate with your server in the background, send the data to it so it can process it. You send a separate request in the background which happens without reloading the page.

Please be aware of the distinction between the client (where the JavaScript is run) and the server (where PHP generated the page run by the client).

If you want to use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/), that library [has some decent functions](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) that makes it easier to implement cross-browser AJAX requests. However I would suggest first researching the topic.